# Euclidean embedding of the mesh

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

$M$ is  a topological mesh, i.e. triple $M=(V,E,F)$, where $V$ is the vertex, $E$ is the edge and $F$ is the face, such that $M$ is homeomorphic to the sphere.

Suppose that we have  a metric $l :E\to\mathbb R^+$( on each triangle of $F$, $l$ satisfies the triangle inequality) with positive sectional curvature.

**Q** Is there a method to embed $M$ to the three-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$, such that two vertices' distance coincides with the distance of metric $l$.

Is there any reference about the question.